# Can changing the defined inner product change wheather a transformation is Normal or Self Adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

[Excercise 1 reffered to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVcFG.png)
**Only need answer to d**

Excercise 1 (in text): Given the (complex) linear space spanned by {$\sin x$, $\cos x$, $e^{2x}$} . On this space we
define the linear mapping T as the derivative, i.e. ,

$T(f) = \frac{df}{dx}$

(a) Determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T.

(b) Prove that T is diagonisable.

(c) Determine the eigenvalues of the inverse of T.

Only need answer to d) as follows:

d) Let T be the operator from Exercise 1. There exists an inner product on the space spanned by {$\sin x$, $\cos x$, $e^{2x}$} such that T becomes self-adjoint or normal.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. The eigenvalues of $T$ are $\pm i$ and $2$. Since it has some non-real eigenvalues, it cannot be self-adjoint, regardless of the inner product being used.

Comment: I know right. But I am still stumped on how to give the proof for this. Can you give an answer if this is possible in general, as in can changing the inner product change anything about the transformation in terms of being normal over self adjoint?